# difficulties exposing my express docker container to the world

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a node app running using express to run a webserver in a docker container.  My node app looks a little like this:

```
'use strict'
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const express = require('express');
... // so many requires


const main = async () => {
  var app = express();

  app.get('/status', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World')
  });

  app.listen(8080,'0.0.0.0');

  ... // so much more code

}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my node app, because when I log into my docker container using: **docker exec -it blacklist-service_blacklist-service_run_1 /bin/bash**

And running: **curl localhost:8080/status**

It returns *Hello World*

So it leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my docker config, as when I run: **curl localhost:8080/status** from my host machine, I receive: *curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused*

So... my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -qq install \
  curl \
  git \
  gnupg2 \
  locales \
  netcat \
  python3-pip

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN pip3 install abydos \
    num2words \
    simplejson \
    unidecode

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash
RUN apt-get -qq install nodejs
RUN npm install npm@latest -g

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g \
  Eficode/wait-for

RUN npm install \
    express \
    googleapis \
    uuid

COPY src/ .
COPY bin/ ./bin

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT /usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for/wait-for ${WAIT_FOR} -t 20 -- node server.js
```

(i know, i know, but it's a requirement to use ubuntu as our docker image)

I then have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:latest"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - "./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"
  blacklist-service:
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}unicorn/blacklist-service:${DOCKER_IMAGE_LABEL:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./debugging/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - WAIT_FOR=rabbitmq:5672
      - AMQP_SHARED_HOST=rabbitmq
      - AMQP_USERNAME=guest
      - AMQP_PASSWORD
      - AMQP_EXCHANGE=amq.topic
      - AMQP_TOPIC=topic
      - AMQP_JOB=state51::Job::RunQAForFormat
      - AMQP_QUEUE
      - AMQP_PATTERN=#
      - AMQP_SHARED_PORT=5672
      - AMQP_SEND_EXCHANGE=firehose
      - BLACKLIST_SERVICE_SECRET
      - GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
      - GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
      - GOOGLE_API_KEY
```

The *./debugging/Dockerfile* refers to the Dockerfile I listed above.

I then build my image via: **docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml build** and run it with: **docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run blacklist-service** (with *docker-compose.local.yml* being the name of the above docker-compose file).

So where have I gone wrong with exposing my server? running Docker community: **Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764)** on my Mac

Comment: This seems more like an issue with `Docker for Mac`. Do you face a similar issue with other containers too or just this one?

Comment: I haven't tried any other container recently... let me see if i can reproduce with an extremely simple container.

Comment: i can't seem to reproduce it

Comment: Ok so, the difference appears to be between `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run [service name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add the parameter `--service-ports` when using `docker-compose run [service-name]`.

So the right command is: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml run --service-ports blacklist-service` which allows me to curl to **localhost:8080/status** and get the response I was expecting.